How to test gnupg integration in my code?
I received a working PHP class that wraps gnupg. We handle gpg encryption and decryption with it. Now I have to test it with PHPUnit.
Nature of gpg is that it never returns two same results.
How should I test it really works?
This is roughly what I tried, but apparently it can not work:

    public function testExample(): void
    {
        $originalMessageFixture = $this->fixturesDisk->get('pgp/decrypted-message');
        $expectedEncryptedMessage = $this->fixturesDisk->get('pgp/encrypted-message');

        $encryptedMessage = (new PgpWrapper())->encrypt($originalMessageFixture);

        self::assertSame($expectedEncryptedMessage, $encryptedMessage);
    }


Keep in mind that you're not testing GPG here, you're testing the wrapper. You should not be asserting that the process applies any sort of cryptographic strength. You only need to know that the encrypt process changes the input and that the decrypt process gives you back what you started with.
That said, you don't need to start with a known static block of text. So just generate some random input to be your source text. Maybe something like:
$source = base64_encode(random_bytes(1024));

Or:
$source = \Faker\Factory::create()->paragraph();

Then use your class to encrypt that source, and assert that what you get back is different than what you provided:
$encrypted = (new PgpWrapper())->encrypt($source);
self::assertNotSame($source, $encrypted); // or whatever this method is called

Then use your class to decrypt that encrypted message, and assert that what you get back is the same as your source:
$decrypted = (new PgpWrapper())->decrypt($encrypted);
self::assertSame($decrypted, $source);

